# Unrecognized configuration section applicationSettings

Tags: c#

My app runs fine on development PC, but when I start it on a client PC, I get an exception:
"Configuration System failed to initialize", with innerException msg = "Unrecognized configuration section applicationSettings"
I have checked my config file against all solutions I could find on the Internet, but it seems OK. Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated. The config file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="KIM.Eplex.PCMU.PLayer.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="EplexPCMU.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="KIM.Eplex.PCMU.PLayer.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

    <userSettings>
    <KIM.Eplex.PCMU.PLayer.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="DataTransferPath" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="DiagnosticLockTypeIndex" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SystemType" serializeAs="String">
            <value>2</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="NumAuditEvents" serializeAs="String">
            <value>100</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="AuditStartAt" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
        </setting>
    </KIM.Eplex.PCMU.PLayer.Properties.Settings>
    <EplexPCMU.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="centre" serializeAs="String">
            <value>200, 200</value>
        </setting>
    </EplexPCMU.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
<applicationSettings>
    <KIM.Eplex.PCMU.PLayer.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="DiffProgEnabled" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0</value>
        </setting>
    </KIM.Eplex.PCMU.PLayer.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

If it works on your development machine, then there is a problem with the sectionGroup registration.  You have the applicationSettings group registered to the type `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup`.

Check the target machine for the System.Configuration assembly and make sure the version matches the version you have in the sectionGroup registration.